# How can i change location of iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I want to change location of host of iFrame , can it be done like this:

`frame.contentWindow.location.host = "mydomain.com";`

So that inside iframe all src are referred by this location if it has relative route.

Comment: You cannot access an iFrame location unless the content is from the same server as the parent page. If that is the case, you need to change on the server. It seems you are trying to change the `base href` - I would doubt that would work in any case.

Comment: i have api that return html content some script and css tag has relative route in that , so it is trying to fetch from localhost

Comment: So change them when you read the html